# binding a function with conditional logic in scala

Tags: function, scala, binding, scalafx

I am a scala newbie who came from JavaFX 1.3 and this is my first post in stackoverflow

In JavaFX 1.3 I can do something like this

```
property : bind if (condition) value1 else value2
```

In Scala, I attempted doing something like this:

```
property <== function1

def function1() = {
  if (condition)
    value1
  else
    value2
}
```

However, it does not seem to be dynamically working. The expression in the condition of the function evaluates only once when the stage appears. I was kind of expecting the values in that expression are evaluated in realtime.

Specifically, I want to resize something to a certain limit and I am using binding to achieve it. So I want the bound function to keep evaluating the expression and give me the appropriate width of something as I resize other things.

Anyway, I will paste the actual codes below:

```
var stageWidth = DoubleProperty(0)
var stageHeight = DoubleProperty(0)

stageWidth <== stage.scene.width
stageHeight <== stage.scene.height

var origStageWidth = DoubleProperty(stage.scene.width.toDouble)
val origStageHeight = DoubleProperty(stage.scene.height.toDouble)

val origTextClipperWidth = DoubleProperty(textClipper.width.toDouble)
val origTextClipperHeight = DoubleProperty(textClipper.height.toDouble)
val minWidth = DoubleProperty(100)

val origButtonWidth = DoubleProperty(button.prefWidth.toDouble)

textClipper.width <== resize

def resize() ={
    var boolResult = (stageWidth - origStageWidth) + origTextClipperWidth > minWidth
    if (boolResult.value) {
        (stageWidth - origStageWidth) + origTextClipperWidth
    } else {
        minWidth
    }
}

textClipper.height <== (stageHeight - origStageHeight) + origTextClipperHeight
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: From the [homepage of ScalaFx](http://code.google.com/p/scalafx/): `color <== when (hover) choose Color.GREEN otherwise Color.RED`

Comment: thanks senia, I also found it a few days ago and it works

Answer (score 1):

A standard function/method is not an `scalafx.beans.Observable` so it doesn't have the needed "hooks" to invalidate its binding.

A while ago I made some methods to simplify binding creation, just for this purpose.

The following code is used to make functions binding to a string value

```
import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.beans.binding.StringBinding
import scalafx.beans.Observable
import scalafx.collections._
import javafx.collections.ObservableList
import javafx.beans.{ binding => jfxbb }
import jfxbb.ListBinding

def createStringBinding(dependency: Observable*)(computeFunction: => String): StringBinding = 
  new jfxbb.StringBinding {
  //invalidated when the passed dependency becomes invalid
  dependency.foreach(this.bind(_))
  //use the function to compute the new value
  override def computeValue: String = computeFunction
}
```

In your case you should make a Double binding

```
//THIS CODE IS NOT TESTED, MAYBE IT NEEDS A LITTLE TWEAKING

def createDoubleBinding(dependency: Observable*)(computeFunction: => Double): DoubleBinding = 
  new jfxbb.DoubleBinding {
  //invalidated when the passed dependency becomes invalid
  dependency.foreach(this.bind(_))
  //use the function to compute the new value
  override def computeValue: Double = computeFunction
}

//and use it like
val resize = createDoubleBinding(
  stageWidth,
  stageHeight,
  origStageWidth,
  origStageHeight,
  minWidth,
  origButtonWidth) {
    var boolResult = (stageWidth - origStageWidth) + origTextClipperWidth > minWidth
    if (boolResult.value) {
      (stageWidth - origStageWidth) + origTextClipperWidth
    } else {
      minWidth
    }
}

textClipper.width <== resize
```

---

I suppose it's possible to generalize the createXXXBinding with type parameters adapting to available classes of the `javafx.beans.binding` package, but I'm not sure it would be an easy task, since the class hierarchy doesn't help...

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX2+ and [ScalaFX](http://scalafx.org) allow you to dynamically switch two bound properties based on a `BooleanProperty` or `BooleanBinding`. This can be achieved using `when` construct. Your coode

```
property : bind if (condition) value1 else value2
```

can be expressed in ScalaFX as:

```
property <== when (condition) choose value1 otherwise value2
```

In your specific example assume that we create a `width` property that contains dynamically computed width based on the condition `boolResult`

```
val width = DoubleProperty(0)
```

That `width` property is bound to conditional expression using `when` construct

```
width <== when(boolResult) choose ((stageWidth - origStageWidth) + origTextClipperWidth) otherwise minWidth
```

When `boolResult` value is `true` the first part (after choose) is assigned to `width` when it is `false` the part after `otherwise` is assigned. Here is a complete example that shows this in action:

```
import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty

object ConditionalBindigDemo extends App {

  val stageWidth = DoubleProperty(200)
  val origStageWidth = DoubleProperty(100)

  val origTextClipperWidth = DoubleProperty(20)
  val minWidth = DoubleProperty(50)

  val boolResult = (stageWidth - origStageWidth) + origTextClipperWidth > minWidth
  val width = DoubleProperty(0)
  width <== when(boolResult) choose ((stageWidth - origStageWidth) + origTextClipperWidth) otherwise minWidth

  // Simple test
  printState()
  stageWidth() = 150
  printState()
  stageWidth() = 100
  printState()
  stageWidth() = 50
  printState()

  def printState() {
    println("stageWidth: " + stageWidth() + ", origStageWidth: " + origStageWidth() + ", width: " + width())
  }
}
```

When you run it you will get output:

```
stageWidth: 200.0, origStageWidth: 100.0, resizeWidth: 120.0
stageWidth: 150.0, origStageWidth: 100.0, resizeWidth: 70.0
stageWidth: 100.0, origStageWidth: 100.0, resizeWidth: 50.0
stageWidth: 50.0, origStageWidth: 100.0, resizeWidth: 50.0
```